# 'SelectKBest' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

Tags: feature-selection, scikit-learn

I wanted to use SelectKBest chi square for feature selection of categorical data.

df.shape yields (4000,150)

y.shape yields (4000,1)

On using the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, chi2

df_new=SelectKBest(score_func=chi2,k=10).fit_transform(df,y)
```

It shows Attribute Error: 'SelectKBest' object has no attribute '_validate_data'

Any ideas what might be a solution to this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with an example dataset. You need to provide more information about how you got to this error

Answer (score 0):

try different sklean version if using 0.23.2